# sqlite3_open does not return error if trying to open a file that does not exsist

Tags: c, database, sqlite

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){ 
 int rc
 sqlite3 *db;

 rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);

 printf("rc = %d\n", rc);
 if(rc){
    printf("Not Valid Database\n");
    sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(1);
}
```

If I run this with `./test exsisting_database.sqlite3` it returns `0` as expected. But with `./test not_exsisting_database.sqlite3` it still returns `0` and creates the file `not_exsisting_database.sqlite3`

Comment: Creating a database if not found is design intent for `sqlite3_open`.  Take a look at `sqlite3_open_v2` which accepts flags and will return an error code if the database file does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the SQLite documentation on opening a database found here:
https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

> The **sqlite3_open_v2()** interface works like **sqlite3_open()** except that
> it accepts two additional parameters for additional control over the
> new database connection. The flags parameter to sqlite3_open_v2() can
> take one of the following three values, optionally combined with the
> SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX, SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE,
> SQLITE_OPEN_PRIVATECACHE, and/or SQLITE_OPEN_URI flags:
>
> SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY The database is opened in read-only mode. If the
> database does not already exist, an error is returned.
>
> SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE The database is opened for reading and writing
> if possible, or reading only if the file is write protected by the
> operating system. In either case the database must already exist,
> otherwise an error is returned.
>
> SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE The database is opened for
> reading and writing, and is created if it does not already exist.
> **This is the behavior that is always used for sqlite3_open() and sqlite3_open16().**

So you need to use sqlite3_open_v2() without the SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE flag instead of sqlite3_open()